# Select message by contents (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need to select a previously sent message (from a bot) in discord.js

```
async () => {
    let fetched;
    fetched = await receivedMessage.channel.messages.startsWith("Please use the command:")
    fetched.delete()
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm trying to get a message by it's contents, and then delete it.

Edit: So apparently... "You could fetch the last 100 messages using `channel.messages.fetch` with a limit option, then filter that collection by `message.content.startsWith`, and then passing that into `channel.bulkDelete()`"
Which in my opinion, sounds like the way to do it - I will try it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `startsWith` you can just check if the message was sent by a bot using `message.author.bot`.